# Test code confusion

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write test code for the following classes. They all seem very simple, but I'm confused on how to do it. I don't know if this will make sense to anybody but I wanted to see if I could get some help on these two classes :

```
    public with sharing class Milestone1_TestProjectBuilder {

    public Integer numberMilestones { get; set; }
    public Integer numberTasks {get; set; }

    public void buildProject() {

        Milestone1_Project__c newProject = Milestone1_Test_Utility.sampleProjectActive('Sample ' + Datetime.now());
        insert newProject;

        for (Integer i=0; i < numberMilestones; i++) {
            Milestone1_Milestone__c ms = Milestone1_Test_Utility.sampleMilestone(newProject);
            insert ms;
            for (Integer j=0; j < numberTasks; j++) {
                Milestone1_Task__c task = Milestone1_Test_Utility.sampleTask(ms);
                insert task;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

and this one which are essentially just a field validation messages :

```
public with sharing class Milestone1_Move_Exception extends Exception{

    public static final String ERROR_MILESTONE_ALREADY_ASSIGNED_PROJECT = 'A milestone you are attempting to move is already assigned to this project. Please review your selection and try again.';
    public static final String ERROR_TASK_ALREADY_ASSIGNED_MILESTONE = 'A task you are attempting to move is already assigned to this milestone. Please review your selection and try again.';
    public static final String ERROR_MILESTONE_COMPLETE = 'Milestone is Complete, the Task can not be moved';
    public static final String ERROR_MILESTONE_HAS_SUCCESSORS = 'Top Level Milestone has successors and cannot be moved.  Redirect those successors and try again.';
    public static final String ERROR_MILESTONE_HAS_PREDECESSOR = 'Top Level Milestone has predecessor and cannot be moved.  Remove that predecessor and try again.';

    static testMethod void testConstants() 
    {
        //Just a place holder test method for static constants on this exception class.
        system.assert(true);
    }

}
```

and the other one :

```
public with sharing class Milestone1_Import_Exception extends Exception {

    public static final String ERROR_NO_FILE_SELECTED = 'No import XML files selected. Please select an XML file to import.';
    public static final String ERROR_EMPTY_XML = 'The Project cannot be null. This is a critical error during import of XML. Please try exporting and re-importing.';
    public static final String ERROR_INVALID_XML = 'Import Failed -- Milestone was unable to import your file.';
    public static final String ERROR_FILESIZE_TOO_LARGE = 'The XML file is too large.';

}
```

As I'm sure you can tell, I'm a complete rookie to test code. I apologize for asking for help on this and not being able to at least give some. Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what parts you don't understand ? What part are you confused about?after so many question on this subject we'd expect you to start understanding the basics.   Also: I'd strongly discourage from doing DML in for loops.

Comment: Test code would be very easy in this case. I suggest you take a look at this blog which explains very well how to create a good test class. http://blog.tquila.com/2011/11/17/salesforce-testing-best-practices/ and as Sdry says your code is not good you are doing DML statements in loops which will cause your code to fail in a production environment.

Comment: I apologize for the questions. I realize I'm asking basic stuff here, but I'm just learning it right now and it doesn't help that I'm looking at code that was never documented. I'm also confused on what to do to test a class whose main purpose is to produce a validation message. Do I need to create the whole record from scratch in order to create the validation error ? 

Again, I'm sorry. I just don't know where to start on these. I would appreciate the help so much.

Comment: First you should take a step back and fix Milestone1_TestProjectBuilder so it is [bulkified](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code).  Beyond that yes you should always create data in your tests and it would also be more valuable to test the code that utilizes these strings rather than asserting the strings value.

Comment: No need to be sorry, your question is being voted down because you're asking this forum to do your work. There are oodles of articles on writing unit tests in Force.com, I suggest starting there and reading them. Try to write your test. Then come here and ask your specific question about where you are stuck. For example, your question here in the comments in a much better question, about producing a validation message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need to be sorry, the only reason the question is being down voted is it appears as though you are just asking people to write your test code for you.  Take a stab at it, and post it on here asking for some help.  Don't worry about it being incorrect, that's the point of this forum.  People will be much more likely to help out if they feel you have really tried this on your own and are stuck.

Test classes can be very tricky at first, but in general, for tests for basic classes, you can follow just three steps.  These are very basic examples, but should give you some context to look at some of the available documentation and have a base of knowledge

1. **Create your data**

   Let's say your class is a controller for a VF page that lists myObject in a pageBlockTable, and allows you to do 'something' with these records. In order to test the class, you need to have some myObject__c records to work with.

   > ```
   > myObject__c o1 = new myObject__c(name = 'test1', .......);
   > insert o1;
   > myObject__c o2 = new myObject__c(name = 'test2', .......);
   > insert o2;
   > ```
2. **Instantiate the class**

   In order to use this class and test the methods, you need to instantiate the class, that is fairly simple

   > `myClass controller = new myClass();`
3. **Test the logic within that class**

   Lets assume you allow a user to remove one of the myObject__c records on the VF page from the list with a myCustomDelete method.  Lets also assume you hold the list of myObjects in a controller property myObjectList.

   > ```
   > integer listSize = controller.myObjectList.size(); 
   > controller.myCustomDelete();
   > system.assertEquals(controller.myObjectList.size(), listSize - 1);
   > ```

If you take a look at some of hte sugested documentation from teh comments on your question, and use this to try to take a stab at writing a test class, and then edit your question with that, people will definitly try to help you to get it working.  In general, I think most people just ignore questions that ask for people to write code for them, so just take a stab at it, don't worry about it not being correct.

By not writing the code for you, people really are just trying to help you in the long run

***Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime...***

Comment: I've also been referred to here : http://jessealtman.com/2013/09/proper-unit-test-structure-in-apex/

written by @JesseAltman who is on here very often as well.

Comment: Yes, that is a great reference, and Jesse Altman always has quality stuff.  Good luck Zoom