# why am I getting this error in this code(Attempt to de-reference a null object)?

Tags: unit-test

Hi I am tring to write test class for controller class for updating contact records.

```
public class updatecon{

    public id tobeEdited{get; set;}
    list<contact> lstcontact = [SELECT ID,name, Firstname,lastname,email,phone from contact];

    public void saveRecord(){
        Contact tobeupdated;
        for(Contact temp : lstcontact){
            if(temp.id==tobeEdited){
                tobeupdated = temp;   
                break;
            }
        }
        update tobeupdated;
        tobeEdited = null;
    }
}
```

test class:

```
@istest
public class testupdatecon{
    public static testMethod void testMyController(){
        updatecon update = new updatecon();
        update .saveRecord();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test code confusion](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17524/test-code-confusion)

Comment: I would check out this answer (there are also many others)  [http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17524/test-code-confusion]

Comment: No thats not me...

Comment: I tried Above test class what i posted i am getting error:System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object........... "lstcontact "returning 0 records can u you help on this why this is showing like this..

Comment: user321 see the reason no one has been able to answer is because you're not asking the right question.  The answer to "how to write a test class" is what @chris is refering too.  If that question and answers do not help you may need to ask a different question here (feel free to update your post), such as "why am I getting this error in this code" or "how to test a for-loop iteration in apex".  Getting good answers depends on the focus of the question, please try to improve your question.

Comment: @samuel thank for your suggestion jow i changed question

Comment: (put the error in your question too!)

Answer (score 3):

When your test class runs, it does not have access to the data in your organisation, so the line:

```
list<contact> lstcontact = [SELECT ID,name, Firstname,lastname,email,phone from contact];
```

is not going to get anything.. when your test calls `saveRecord` there is nothing to iterate over, and thus you get the 0 records error.

You need to "insert" a contact before calling your method, so the test context has something to play with...

```
@istest
public class testupdatecon{
    public static testMethod void testMyController() {
      Contact c = new Contact(Firstname='bob',lastname='test',email='test@example.com',phone='0101010101');
      insert c;
      updatecon updateCon = new updatecon();
      updateCon.tobeEdited = c.Id;
      updateCon.saveRecord();
    }
}
```

I think I can also see a couple of other flaws in your test re: whether it will do what you want, but that should at least stop the error you are mentioning in your comment above.

Edit: I have added the `updateCon.tobeEdited = c.Id;` bit (and fiddled your variable name away from "update" which is a terrible idea)... so now your method will actually update a record. You really shouldn't have an uninstantiated contact record being updated based on whether a for/if runs in your code, or you will get loads of null pointers in your real life..

Comment: I Updated my code with your code but i m getting same error could you pleas e tell me any another way

Comment: the null is coming from "update tobeupdated;" - you never instantiate tobeupdated in your code because you don't set tobeedited.

Comment: In My code these two lines not covering """tobeupdated = temp;   break;            }        }
        update tobeupdated;        tobeEdited = null; """

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning value in `tobeEdited` property, so when you are using in the if statement, it is throwing error.

You need to check the below code

```
@istest
public class testupdatecon{
    public static testMethod void testMyController() {
      Contact c = new Contact(Firstname='bob',lastname='test',email='test@example.com',phone='0101010101');
      insert c;
      updatecon updateClassObject = new updatecon();
      updateClassObject.tobeEdited = c.Id;
      update .saveRecord();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: sorry i used this code but  getting same error attempt to dereference null object and these two lines not covering tobeupdated = temp;break; update tobeupdated;
        tobeEdited = null; these lines not covering

Comment: are you still getting error?

Comment: yes  still i am getting same error

Comment: can you please post full error message

Comment: ERROR:: NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: can you please put some debug logs and check if the temp.Id and tobeEdited fields are not null or what is the size of Id in both fields.

Comment: temp|Contact|true|false temp|{"s":1,"v":{"Id":"0032800000EYYMCAA5","Name":"bob test","FirstName":"bob","LastName":"test","Email":"test@example.com","Phone":"0101010101"}}|0x1bbc12d temp|null System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: This only debuglog here temp showing null

Answer (score 0):

I made some edits to your code. You still need to add your asserts after you test your class, but you will get code coverage. Please mark this as helpful if it helps.

```
public class updatecon{
      public id tobeEdited{get; set;} 
      list<contact> lstcontact = [SELECT ID,name, Firstname,lastname,email,phone from contact]; 
      public updatecon(){} 
      public void saveRecord(){ 
        List<Contact> tobeupdated=new list<contact>(); 
        for(Contact temp : lstcontact){ 
            if(temp.id==tobeEdited){ 
                tobeupdated.add( temp);    
                break; 
            } 
        } 
        update tobeupdated; 

    } 
} 

@istest public class testupdatecon {
    @istest  static void testMyController(){
        for(integer x=0;x<20;x++){
            contact con=new contact(lastname=string.valueof('last '+x), firstname=string.valueOf('first '+x), email='x@x.com', phone='5555555555');
        }
        System.test.startTest();
        updatecon updater = new updatecon();
        updater.saveRecord();
        System.test.stopTest();
    }
}
```